# $.connection is undefined + signalR 0.5.3 + MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Been struggling with this error the paste two hours..

```
TypeError: $.connection is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

var chatHubClient = $.connection.chatHub;
```

here is my Chat.cs (which is in the controller folder - my guess is this is what I'm doing wrong, but I can't find any documentation on where to put it or how to route it)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SignalR.Hubs;

namespace SingalrTest.Controllers
{
    public class Chat
    {
        private readonly static Lazy<Chat> _instance = new Lazy<Chat>(() => new Chat());

        public static Chat Instance
        { get { return _instance.Value; } }
    }

    [HubName("chatHub")]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly int TimeoutInSeconds = 30;
        private readonly Chat _chat;

        public ChatHub() : this(Chat.Instance) { }

        private ChatHub(Chat chat)
        {
            this._chat = chat;
        }

        public void Join(string channelName)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Someone joined " + channelName);
        }
    }
}
```

And at last,.. the might _Layout.cs.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.3.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/signalr/hubs")

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // var chatHubClient = jQuery.connection.chatHub;
                var chatHubClient = $.connection.chatHub;

                $.connection.chatHub.start(function () {
                    chatHubClient.join('TEST');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
    </body>
</html>
```

And if I visit the /signalr/hubs I can see that the source is generated correctly. So what biggy am I missing?

Comment: I'm having this same problem. For some reason $.connection is not defined when the $.ready event happens.

I sort of fixed it by running my code inline instead of on the ready event... I have no idea why it disappears though...

Answer (score 8):

you may have moved on...

But here's the solution.

you have all your scripts in the right order in the head tag. But the `_Layout.cshtml` from the Visual Studio template has following lines at the end of the body tag.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

This bundle has the jQuery library, which overwrites the $ object when it loads. So any 'stuff' on this setup by SignalR are now overwritten and are not accessible.

simply use following in your page.

```
@section scripts {
    @* Load your scripts here. (and remove jQuery, coz it's already loaded) *@
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will jQuery be properly bundled though when it's loaded though? I'd rather let the bundler load jQuery as part of the bundle and then re-run the signalR stuff.

Comment: yes. You only have to load SignalR. and make sure you load it AFTER jQuery. (scripts section runs after loading jQuery. scripts in <head> runs before.. in the default configuration.)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/22/announcing-the-release-of-signalr-0-5-3.aspx), for version 0.5.3, you have to change the connection syntax:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
```

or direct traffic to a secondary server

```
var connection = $.hubConnection("http://localhost:58416/");
```

connect to hub:

```
var hub = connection.createProxy('your_hub_name');
```

And some more changes when sending and receiving message as well

Hope this help