# SignalR not working : $.connection.client is null or undefined

Tags: signalr

After spending two days getting this working with no success, finally I am asking this question here.

Background: I am trying to use SignalR to send real-time data from my desktop application to all web pages.

What I have is, a console application (this just to get concept working then will move it to active project) that needs to send real time data to a webpage built in asp .net. Both are using .Net 4.

In IE9 it shows me error in debug mode at line "chat.client.broadcastMessage = " saying chat.client is null or undefined.

In firfox, it doesn't show me that error but it's not working/not doing anything and the problem is the same as it's not showing me alert('asking for name'); window so I guess it's not getting there and throwing error before that.

Here's my web page code. This is new separate web site project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SignalR Simple Chat</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            background-color: #99CCFF;
            border: thick solid #808080;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
        <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        <ul id="discussion">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.json-2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->

    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.--> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            alert('starting scrip');
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
            $.connection.hub.url = 'http://<ipaddressORlochost>:8080/chatroom';
            alert($.connection.hub);
            alert($.connection.hub.url);
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            alert(chat);
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                // Html encode display name and message. 
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                // Add the message to the page. 
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };
            alert('asking for name');
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.  
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start({ jsonp:true}).done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
-------------------------
```

I have tried removing below line and also adding "/signalr" at the end.

$.connection.hub.url = 'http://:8080/chatroom';

Here's my desktop application (server) code.

```
class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            using (WebApplication.Start<Startup>(@"http://<ipaddressORlochost>:8080/chatroom"))
            {

                while (true)
                {
                   // GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>().Clients.All.addMessage("dsf","asdfd");
                    Console.WriteLine("Tags sent :" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
            }

        }

 class Startup
    {

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain=true };
            app.MapHubs(config);
        }
    }

    public class ChatHub : Hub
     {
        public void Send(string b,string a)
        {
          try
           {
                Clients.All.broadcastMessage(b,a);
            }
             catch { }
        }
     }
```

ANY HELP WOULD BE REALLY APPRECIATED.

Thanks All in advance.

-------------- FOUND THE ANSWER ---------- HAVE EDIT THIS QUESTION AS CANNOT ANSWER MY OWN QUESTION WITHIN 8 HOURS

Hi ALL

Just in case if some one else having same problem. I have found answer/fixed.

THANKS TO **[Hatake Kakashi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396233/connection-is-undefined-signalr-0-5-3-mvc4/16160077#16160077)**

Main issue was that $.connection is now changed to  $.hubConnection

Here's what I had to change.

Script in my web page. I have left commented code to show what's been replaced with what.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            alert('starting scrip');
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
            // $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:8080/chatroom';
            var conn = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:8080/chatroom');

            alert($.connection.hub);
            alert($.connection.hub.url);

            var chat = conn.createHubProxy('chatHub'); //$.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            alert(chat);
            //            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            //                // Html encode display name and message. 
            //                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            //                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
            //                // Add the message to the page. 
            //                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
            //                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            //            };
            chat.on('addMessage', function (a, message) {

                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + $('<div />').text(a).html()
                                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + $('<div />').text(message).html() + '</li>');

            });

            alert('asking for name');
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.  
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            conn.logging = true;
            // Start the connection
            conn.start().done(function () {
                alert("Now connected!");
            }).fail(function () {
                alert("Could not Connect!");
            });


//            $.connection.hub.start({ jsonp: true }).done(function () {
//                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
//                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
//                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
//                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
//                    $('#message').val('').focus();
//                });
//            });
        });
    </script>
```

And on the server side (desktop application), because it's one way only I don't need to anything in my ChatHub

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            using (WebApplication.Start<Startup>(@"http://localhost:8080/chatroom"))
            {

                while (true)
                {
                    GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>().Clients.All.addMessage("dsf", "Tags sent :" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Tags sent :" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }

        }

 class Startup
    {

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain=true };
            app.MapHubs(config);
        }
    }
 public class ChatHub : Hub
       {
            /public void Send(string b, string a)
           //{
           //    try
           //    {
           //        Clients.All.addMessage(b, a);
           //    }
           //    catch { }
           //}
       }
```

Hope this will help others.

Comment: You should move the 'answer' portion into an answer now that the 8 hours have passed, it will help others see that this question does have a resolution.